# Google sheet formula to group by variables

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to learn Googlesheet arrayformulas

I've created a sheet @ https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F9tuDleDn4dqg0WEkChl6dMChgWRs-KAPzQJE09tAJM/edit?usp=sharing

Please help me figure out how to:

Using ArrayFormulas:

1. Sort table by latest to oldest Date
2. In Position Column, if paranthesis exists, show paranthesis value in new column
3. In Position Column, If "Major" or "Minority" or "Director" exists then null, show remaining value in new column
4. How do I group into new table  "Date", "Bonus", "Bonus Amount" column by specific Name (e.g. Johnson D. Zoe) and sort by latest date?
5. How do I group into new table, "Date", "Bonus", "Bonus Amount", "Name", "Position" of all records who have Bonus = Y within the Last 30 days vs. within the last Year? ("2023")

Comment: Honestly this feels more of like someone's homework?!

Answer (score 1):

1, 2 and 3:

```
=SORT({A2:D13, 
 TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(E2:E13, "Major|Minority|Director|\(.*\)", )), 
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(E2:E13, "\((.*)\)"))}, 1, 0)
```

[image]

---

4:

```
=QUERY(SORT(A2:D13, 1, 0), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col4 = 'Johnson D. Zoe'", )
```

---

5:

```
=QUERY(SORT({A2:D13, 
 TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(E2:E13, "Major|Minority|Director|\(.*\)", )), 
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(E2:E13, "\((.*)\)"))}, 1, 0), 
 "where Col2 = 'Y' and year(Col1) = 2023", )
```

and:

```
=QUERY(SORT({A2:D13, 
 TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(E2:E13, "Major|Minority|Director|\(.*\)", )), 
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(E2:E13, "\((.*)\)"))}, 1, 0), 
 "where Col2 = 'Y' and Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-30, "e-m-d")&"'", )
```

Comment: Hi - thank you for your directions. I have a few follow-ups, which I've included in the updated spreadsheet. See #6 and #7.

Comment: I added to spreadsheet 6 - 9 for you to please help if possible. Thank you